# Notation in Folland

Tags: real-analysis

When stating Fubini's Theorem it is written that if $f \in L^+(X \times Y)$ $\dots$.

This may be inappropriate to ask on this site but I cannot find the notation $L^+$ defined anywhere on the previous pages. What is the meaning of this  notation?

Comment: You have no idea how many times I have asked myself this same question. It is difficult to find. The definition is used in the monotone convergence theorem, so it is on the page before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 49, he says

[image]

$${}{}{}$$